# Get a notification/event/signal when a Qt widget gets focus

Tags: qt, focus

In Qt, when a widget receives focus, how can get a notification about it, so I can execute some custom code? Is there a signal or an event for that?

Answer (score 41):

You can add en `event filter`.
This is an example of an application written with **QtCreator**. This form has a **QComboBox** named ***combobox***.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboBox->installEventFilter(this);
    .
    .
    .
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
    {
        if (object == ui->comboBox)
        {
            qWarning(object->objectName().toLatin1().data());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

There is a "focusChanged" signal sent when the focus changes, introduced in Qt 4.1.
It has two arguments, he widget losing focus and the one gaining focus:

```
void QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget * old, QWidget * now)
```

Comment: For reference, here is the function in Qt docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged

Answer (score 13):

Qt Designer isn't designed for this level of WYSIWYG programming.

Do it in C++:

```
class LineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    virtual void focusInEvent( QFocusEvent* )
    {}
};
```

Comment: what is meant by WYSIWYG programming ?

Comment: WYSIWYG : What You See Is What You Get. This is what MS Word tries. LaTex for example is "WYSIWYM" - What You See Is What You Mean - the produced pdf differs from the text/code you wrote.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to connect a slot to the QApplication::focusChanged signal.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to play with it, but just looking at the QT Documentation, there is a "focusInEvent".  This is an event handler.

Here's how you find information about.... Open up "QT Assistant".  Go to the Index.  Put in a "QLineEdit".  There is a really useful link called "List of all members, including inherited members" on all the Widget pages.  This list is great, because it even has the inherited stuff.

I did a quick search for "Focus" and found all the stuff related to focus for this Widget.

Answer (score 2):

You have hit on of the weird splits in QT, if you look at the documentation `focusInEvent` is not a slot it is a protected function, you can override it if you are implementing a subclass of your widget. If you you just want to catch the event coming into your widget you can use [`QObject::installEventFilter`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qobject.html#installEventFilter) it let's you catch any kind of events.

For some odd reason the developers of Trolltech decided to propagate UI events via two avenues, signals/slots and `QEvent`

Comment: You can override a virtual base function. That is why events are virtual functions. Trolltech use signals instead when inheritance for that functionality is not likely to be useful.

Comment: Events and Signal/Slots are quite different. For example, the order in which receivers receive events is clearly defined, and processing is stopped once the event is handled.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anybody looking for two QMainWindow focus change . 
You can use

```
if(e->type() == QEvent::WindowActivate)
{
    //qDebug() << "Focus IN " << obj << e ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

QWidget::setFocus() is slot, not signal. You can check if QLineEdit is in focus with [focus property](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qwidget.html#focus-prop). QLineEdit emits signals when text is changed or edited, see documentation.