# What is the signal for when a widget loses focus?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qdialog

In a dialog, when the <kbd>tab</kbd> key is pressed, the focus changes to another widget. In Qt, is there any signal for when a widget loses its focus? Can I use it to check if the input is valid or not? If not, can I set the focus back and ask the user to re-input?

Comment: If you're interested in a `QLineEdit` losing focus, the `QLineEdit::editingFinished()` signal captures that event.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's no signal but if you want to know when your widget has lost focus, override and reimplement `void QWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* event)` in your widget. It will be called whenever your widget has lost focus. To give focus to a widget, use `QWidget::setFocus(Qt::FocusReason)`.

To validate input in a `QLineEdit` or `QComboBox` you can subclass `QValidator` and implement your own validator, or use one of the existing subclasses, `QIntValidator`, `QDoubleValidator`, or `QRegExpValidator`. Set the validator with `QLineEdit::setValidator(const QValidator*)` and `QComboBox::setValidator(const QValidator*)` respectively.

If you want to validate the contents of a modal dialog box, one way would be to override `QDialog::exec()` with an implementation like this:

```
int MyDialog::exec() {
  while (true) {
    if (QDialog::exec() == QDialog::Rejected) {
      return QDialog::Rejected;
    }
    if (validate()) {
      return QDialog::Accepted;
    }
  }
}

bool MyDialog::validate() {
  if (lineEdit->text().isEmpty()) {
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Invalid value", "The specified value is not valid");
    lineEdit->setFocus();
    lineEdit->selectAll();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It will not allow the user to close the dialog with the OK button or any other button with the Accepted role unless the contents of the dialog is successfully validated. In this example I assume the dialog has a `QLineEdit` named `lineEdit` and the `validate` function will make sure that its content is not empty. If it is, it will set the focus to the `QLineEdit` and show the dialog again.

Comment: There actually is a signal - [`QApplication::focusChanged`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#focusChanged).

Comment: [sashoalm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492336/sashoalm)'s pithy comment should be the accepted answer. Of course, it doesn't work like that. Consider upvoting [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321677/2809027) at [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321656/get-a-notification-event-signal-when-a-qt-widget-gets-focus) instead. `</sigh>`

Answer (score 14):

It is also possible (and easier) to create the signal yourself

In the .cpp (do not forget to include the moc)

```
class FocusWatcher : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit FocusWatcher(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
   {
      if (parent)
         parent->installEventFilter(this);
   }
   virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override
   {
      Q_UNUSED(obj)
      if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
         emit focusChanged(true);
      else if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
         emit focusChanged(false);

      return false;
   }

Q_SIGNALS:
   void focusChanged(bool in);
};
```

And to connect it:

```
connect(new FocusWatcher(myWidget), &FocusWatcher::focusChanged, this, &View::doSomething);
```

Comment: While the first answer is a more solid approach, this one is way more specific towards the question, since it not requiring to alter the source of the event that one might not have access to.