# Qt Validators - how do I reject intermediate results?

Tags: c++, qt, validation, qlineedit

As far as I understand, a validator can return three results: Invalid, Intermediate and Acceptable.
Suppose my line edit has a regexp validator set with the following regular expression:

```
[ab][cd]
```

So, valid values are: `ac`, `ad`, `bc`, `bd`:

If I try to enter any other character, such as `e` or `0`, the line edit will not let me enter it physically. However, if I enter `a` and switch to another control, it will have no problems with it, although the value `a` is not acceptable, but rather, intermediate.

Here's what I am after. I want the line edit to refuse me to switch focus to any other control if its input is not acceptable. That is, I need to enter a line which fully satisfies my regular expression so that I can switch focus. Otherwise I want my form/dialog etc to refuse me the ability to switch focus.

Is there a straightforward one-liner way to do this or do I have to do this manually? If the latter, what's the standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [QApplication::focusChanged()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#focusChanged) signal. You can catch that, and explicitly check in it if the result for your widget is valid or intermediate, and take suitable action.

I am not aware of a one-liner solution, but it might still exist. My solution is a bit more manual.

Also see [What is the signal for when a widget loses focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818059/what-is-the-signal-for-a-when-a-widget-loses-focus)