# Qt get active text box

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

If I have two text boxes in my main window how can I check which one is active/being used by the user?

Comment: [That][1] should be a good start point to start from...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321656/when-a-qt-widget-gets-focus

Answer (score 3):

You can use [QApplication::focusWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#focusWidget) function to see which widget currently has focus.

Or you can use the [QWidget::hasFocus()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#focus-prop) function to see if your text box has focus.

```
   edit_A = new QTextEdit(this);
   edit_B = new QTextEdit(this);
   .
   .
   .
void MyClass::someFunction()
{
   if(edit_A->hasFocus())
      //edit_A is being used
   else if(edit_B->hasFocus())
      //edit_B is being used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is right but just in case you want to monitor more components you can use

```
QWidget * QApplication::focusWidget ()
```

to get widget with focus.

This approach will allow you to make cleaner code if you wanted to have more widgets monitored. Instead of having a ladder of ifs just use some kind of look-up table to choose what action to take.